# insert function is doesn't add a new elements

Tags: c++

I wrote a program which should to insert elements in the list compare with their costs, but it doesn't work. I enter one element and then program doesn't work. And I can't understand what's wrong.

here is an exactly the exercise:

### Modify the list, so elements on the list are ordered by price. New items added to the list should be inserted into the right place

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef struct listt
{
    string name;
    float price;
    struct listt *next;
}listt;

typedef listt* listPtr;

void insertt(listPtr *, string, float);
void printList(listPtr);
void instruct();

int main()
{
    unsigned int choice;
    float costs;
    string itemName;

    listPtr head = NULL;

    instruct();
    cin >> choice;

    while(choice != 3)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Please enter the name of the item:" << endl;
            cin >> itemName;
            cout << "Please enter the cost of item: " <<endl;
            cin >> costs;
            insertt(&head, itemName, costs);
            break;
        case 2:
            printList(head);
            break;
        }
        cout<<"Choose the operation\n";
        cin >> choice;
    }

    cout<<"end of operation";
    return 0;
}

void instruct(void)
{
    cout<<"Choose the operation\n" << "1.Fill the list\n" << "2.Print the list\n" << "3.End operation\n";
}

void insertt(listPtr *itemList, string nm, float cst)
{

    listPtr previousPt;
    listPtr currentPt;
    listPtr newPtr;

if(newPtr != NULL){
    newPtr->name = nm;
    newPtr->price = cst;
    newPtr->next = *itemList;
}

    previousPt = NULL;
    currentPt = *itemList;

    while(currentPt != NULL && cst > currentPt->price )
    {
        previousPt = currentPt;
        currentPt = currentPt->next;
    }

    if(currentPt == NULL)
    {
        newPtr->next = *itemList;
        *itemList = newPtr;
    } else{
    previousPt->next = newPtr;
    newPtr->next = currentPt;
    }
}

void printList(listPtr hh)
{
    while(hh->next != NULL)
    {
        cout << hh->name <<" " << hh->price<< endl;
        hh = hh->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in *insertt* :

> ```
> void insertt(listPtr *itemList, string nm, float cst)
> {
>
>    listPtr previousPt;
>    listPtr currentPt;
>    listPtr newPtr;
>
>    if(newPtr != NULL){
>      newPtr->name = nm;
>      newPtr->price = cst;
>      newPtr->next = *itemList;
>    }
> ```

*newPtr* is not initialized but you compare its value to NULL then may be modify an unknown block of memory, this is an undefined behavior

replace `listPtr newPtr;` by `listPtr newPtr = new listt;`

That comes because of `typedef listt* listPtr;` hidding the pointer, do not define *typedef* hiding pointer, this is always a source of problem

Your way to insert the new cell is wrong, for instance if the second insert cell as a lower price than the first you have an illegal memory access. A working solution is :

```
void insertt(listt ** itemList, string nm, float cst)
{
    listt * newCell = new listt;

    newCell->name = nm;
    newCell->price = cst;
    newCell->next = nullptr;

    if (*itemList == nullptr)
      *itemList = newCell;
    else {
      for (;;) {
        if (cst < (*itemList)->price) {
          newCell->next = *itemList;
          *itemList = newCell;
          return;
        }
        if ((*itemList)->next == nullptr) {
          (*itemList)->next = newCell;
          return;
        }
        itemList = &(*itemList)->next;
      }
    }
}
```

---

Note *printList* is erroned because the last element is never print, replace

> ```
>   while(hh->next != NULL)
> ```

by

```
while(hh != NULL)
```

or better

```
while(hh != nullptr)
```

---

Your `struct listt` is defined like in C

You need also to check your input are valid, your `cin >> x;` must be `if (! (cin >> x)) { ..error management .. }`